# two same views with different names in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a view UsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit and it is working fine.
My question is that when i copy the same code of that view in another view named xyz it gives the error resource you are looking for is removed.
I need to copy the same code to another view is that possbile ?
here is the code my working view.

```
 @model MyYello.Admin.Models.UsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "UsersWhoHaveConsumedFreeCredit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<body>
<h2>Scheduled Calls</h2>
 <div class="filter" id="ScheduleCalldiv">@Html.Action("ScheduledCalls")</div>
 <hr />
  <h2>Users Who Have Consumed Free Credit</h2>
   <div class="filter">@Html.Partial("CallHistoryFilter", Model.CallHistoryFilter)</div>
 <div id="mainContent" class="results" style="clear: both;">@Html.Partial("CallHistory", Model.CallHistory)    </div>
</body>

 <script type="text/JavaScript">
 <!--
  function AutoRefresh( t ) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);

   }

 function abc() {
$.get("../Admin/ScheduledCalls", function (data) {

    document.getElementById("ScheduleCalldiv").innerHTML = data;
    alert(data);
    $ScheduleCall.replaceWith(data);
  });; 

}
 $(function () {

window.setTimeout("abc", 20000);


 });

  </script>
```

Comment: Do you add the action method for xyz

Comment: Or you are on same tab of view called xyz while running application.

Comment: No i havent added any action method .

Comment: To call this view you have to add action method in your controller

Comment: OR call the view like `return View("xyz");`